# Remove spans with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace all the `span` elements in a set of `td`. They have this content:

```
<span class='close_span'>
    <input type="button" class="close_pop_btn removebtn"/>
</span>
```

The full `td` is like this:

```
<td>
    <span class='close_span'>
        <input type="button" class="close_pop_btn removebtn"/>
    </span>
    <!-- other tags here -->
</td>
```

I want to remove all the `span` elements with the class `close_span` in all the tds and get the resulting string in a jquery/javascript variable. Is that possible, and if so how?

Comment: Can describe _"and get the resulting string in a jquery/javascript variable?"_ ? "resulting string" of `td` element ? Or, removed `span` element as string ?

Comment: resulting string of the td after the removal of the span!

Comment: $('.close_span').on('click',function(){$(this).parent().html()+=$(this).html();$(this).remove();});

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.end()` at close of `.remove()` , which should return `document` , `.find()` with selector `"table"` . From here can select to return entire `table` `html` using `.get()` , `.outerHTML` ; alternatively all `td` `html` using `.find(table td).map(function() {return this.outerHTML}).get()`

```js
var tableHTML = $("table span").remove().end()
.find("table").get(0).outerHTML;

console.log(tableHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class='close_span'>
        <input type="button" class="close_pop_btn removebtn"/>
    </span>
        <!-- other tags here -->
        <div>div 1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>
        <span class='close_span'>
        <input type="button" class="close_pop_btn removebtn"/>
    </span>
        <!-- other tags here -->
        <div>div 2</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only td's content after remove spans:

```
var tdsWithoutSpan = $('td')
  .find('> span.close_span')
  .remove()
  .end();

tdsWithoutSpan.each(function (index, td) {
  console.log(td);
});
```

But if you want table's content:

```
var table = $('table')
  .find('td > span.close_span')
  .remove()
  .end();

console.log(table.parent().html());
```

Comment: Thanks let me try it out!

Comment: Actually what I was trying to ask was this!
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="removebtn"></span><!---Other Stuff--></td>
       </tr>
 <tr>
            <td><span class="removebtn"></span><!---Other Stuff--></td>
       </tr>
</table>
So what i want to do is remove all the occurences of the span in the whole table and get the remaining html!